# Binding value of object from service to object in controller by the reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have an issue with binding object from Angular service to object to Angular controller by the reference. I am making some http request in my service, like in the following pseudo code:

```
this.object = {};
http_request -> then this.object = response
```

And in my controller, I have the following:

```
this.controllerObject = MyService.object
```

However, when the response comes from the server, the value in controller is not updated - is still defined as empty object. Where am I doing mistake?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Alright, I found out that using following method makes it work:

```
angular.copy(response,this.object)
```

But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.object = {};
http_request -> then this.object = response
```

When you do this, you say that 
1st line: I will assign `this.object` property to an **empty object** (reference to location A)
2nd line: I will assign `this.object` property to the `response` object (reference to location B)

Then in your controller

```
this.controllerObject = MyService.object
```

When you initialize you controller like this, you say that i'll assign `this.controllerObject` to `MyService.object`. At that time, `MyService.object` is pointing to location A (because 1st line in service's already executed).

Then you call your service (i suppose that you call this following line later on in your flow)

```
http_request -> then this.object = response
```

after this line `this.object` will point to location B, it do not change data in location A so location still remain **empty object**  => your controllerObject property is not changes as well.

About your update, you can check document of [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy). It say:

> If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it.

It mean angular.copy will not create a new reference, instead of that it will update the destination location with new value. That's the reason that you update's working.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you bind to response which is an inner variable in the callback function of the http promise. 
(this.object and this.controllerObject refer to response vanishes outside it's function's scope)

In the second case you make a copy to the scope seen by both (this.object and this.controllerObject)